# IntelliJ doesnt start - AccessDeniedException

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to run IntelliJ Ultimate Edition I'm getting following error. I tried to reinstall IDE , restart laptop , delete IDEA directories ... nothing helped. I cannot even see welcome popup so I'm not able to change configuration. Any idea what can be wrong and how can I fix this ? Thanks in advance for help!

[image: error]

Comment: The exception in the stack trace says: "Access denied to /Users/Library/.../IntelliJIdea2022.1". What are the permissions of that directory, as which user do you run IDEA, and may that already answer your question? Did you already follow the guide from the first line of the error message?

Comment: What was it actually? If it was a permissions issue, I wonder why reinstalling IDEA didn't help.

Comment: Dont know why but I didnt have Idea folder installed. I tried to reinstall IntelliJ many times but it didnt help. Installing community version and coping idea folder solved the issue.

Comment: If you have the antivirus/firewall - make sure they do not block the IDE. Try with av/firewall disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan.